# Datatables eliminar o ordering numa coluna

Tags: jquery-plugins

Alguém sabe me dizer que se é possivel eliminar o ordering numa coluna no Datatables? E que a coluna em questão é para meter botões e não tem muita lógica ter um ordering.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução para o problema :

```
aoColumnDefs: [
      {
         bSortable: false,
         aTargets: [ -1 ]
      }
    ]
```